# g++ can't find libavcodec, but gcc can

Tags: c++, c, gcc, libav, libavcodec

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 trying to compile some code that uses libav. Take the following example script:

```
// main.c

#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

int main()
{
    avcodec_find_encoder((enum AVCodecID) 0);
    return 0;
}
```

If I build this with `gcc test.c -lavcodec` it builds just fine, but if I build it with `g++ test.c -lavcodec` I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccHxMTp1.o: in function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `avcodec_find_encoder(AVCodecID)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're 'suffering' from C++ name mangling.  Try wrapping the `#include` line with an `extern "C" {`, `}` pair...

```
extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}

int main()
{
    avcodec_find_encoder((enum AVCodecID) 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup, that seems to have done it. Thanks.